# how restart java process in linux form batch file?

Tags: bash, nohup

I want to restart process in linux server.
I use loop for kill and start process.

```
!/bin/bash

pgrep -f java | while read x; 
do 
    addr= pwdx x | awk '{print $2}'
    echo "$addr"
    kill -9 $x
    nohup sh $addr/start.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 
done
```

I store address in a veriable.Then i kill that process and use nohup for start that process.
But process not start.
I think this line is wrong.

```
nohup sh $addr/start.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: `echo "$addr"` should already shown the wrong output, but probably you can't see the difference as the expected output is created by the (wrong) line before. You should use `#!/bin/bash -x` to get debug output, then it's obvious. Btw. What do you expect from `pwdx x`? pwdx expected a pid number

Comment: I give address of process directory from this line
```pwdx x | awk '{print $2}'```

Comment: But I guess, you want `pwdx $x` to use the pid stored in the variable `x`

Comment: ```pwdx x | awk '{print $2}'```
This line print the directory of service that has x pis.
I want ot store in a variable to cd into directory and start service

Answer (score 1):

I see few errors in the script. Line:

```
!/bin/bash
```

must be

```
#!/bin/bash
```

the assignment to `addr` variable is wrong. Instead of this

```
addr= pwdx x | awk '{print $2}'
```

it must be

```
addr=$(pwdx x | awk '{print $2}')
```

Also its wise to redirect STDOUT to file, not to `/dev/null` as this can help debugging and monitoring the app. And you forget to put this in background

```
nohup sh $addr/start.sh >/path/to/standard.log 2>/path/to/error.log &
```